# How to run libsvga program at ubuntu?

Tags: c, graphics, ubuntu

I am trying to use the following program given in the libsvga tutorial.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <vga.h>

    int main(void)
    {
       vga_init();
       vga_setmode(vga_getdefaultmode());
       vga_setcolor(4);
       vga_drawpixel(10, 10);

       sleep(5);
       vga_setmode(TEXT);

       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

I am using following command to compile it

```
   gcc -O3 -o sample sample.c -lvga
```

The output is the following

```
    Using EGA driver
    svgalib 1.4.3
```

and after that nothing happens. I am using ubuntu.
I am wondering if someone can help me in figuring out the problem.

Comment: Are you running this from X or from the console (I mean like pressing ctrl+alt+f1 (ctrl+alt+f7 or f8 to get back))?

Comment: you might have to run it as root, too. you'll likely need at least one other machine to write this kind of code, for when you totally screw everything up.

Comment: Hi, @ user786653 I tried it in console and it gives the same output

Comment: Hi @Tom II am already using it as a root (sudo ./myprog) otherwise it does not execute due to restricted permissions...

Comment: Have you tried any other applications that use libsvga? Also, "EGA driver" sounds a bit suspicious, have you tried using other modes than 'default'?

Comment: I am not aware of such application... Can you please name some so that I can try. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have tried VLc with svgalib plugin. VLC works fine, if you meant this by trying any application which uses svga.

Comment: FWIW I can't get the sample to run on my (x86_64 ubuntu 11.04) machine either. You might have luck editing `/etc/vga/libvga.config` to match your settings. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it didn't work either. I looked around in `/proc/fb` (for the *"framebuffer"* device) and it mentioned `VESA`.

So, I edited the file `/etc/vga/libvga.config` and removed the `#` at the start of the line for VESA chipsets, so it now looks like this:

```
chipset VESA # nicely behaved VESA bioses
```

and `libsvga` seems to work fine.